# Display confirmation message on email sent in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, email

In my ASP.NET application I am unable to show confirmation message to user that email sending is failed or success. I used following code for sending email. What to do to do so?

```
 public void SendMail()
        {
            try
            {
                login = new NetworkCredential("leavesmanagement@nworks.co", "password123456");
                client = new SmtpClient("smtp.1and1.com");
                client.Port = Convert.ToInt32(25);
                client.EnableSsl = true;
                client.Credentials = login;
                msg = new MailMessage { From = new MailAddress("leaves@nworks.co", "nWorks Employee", Encoding.UTF8) };
                msg.To.Add(new MailAddress(this.TextBoxEmail_Mobile.Text));
                msg.Subject = "Recover Password For Your nWorks Leave Management Account";
                msg.CC.Add(new MailAddress("dipak.a.akhade9192@gmail.com"));
                //       msg.CC.Add(new MailAddress("*************user mail id*************"));
                string strBody = string.Empty;
                Guid code = Guid.NewGuid();

                strBody += "<html><head></head><body><p>Click the following link to recover your password.</p>";
                strBody += Environment.NewLine;

                strBody += "<form action='' method='POST' name='myForm1'><a href='http://localhost:19343/ResetPasswordForm.aspx?guid="+code.ToString()+"&userid="+getUser()+"'><b>Reset Password</b></form><br>";


                strBody += "<br/>Thanks.</body></html>";

                msg.Body = strBody;

                msg.BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
                msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
                msg.Priority = MailPriority.Normal;
                msg.DeliveryNotificationOptions = DeliveryNotificationOptions.OnFailure;
                client.SendCompleted += new SendCompletedEventHandler(SendCompletedCallback);
                string userstate = "sending.......";
                client.SendAsync(msg, userstate);

                string q2 = "select count(*) from RecoverPwdStatus where uid='"+getUser()+"';";
                MySqlCommand cmd2 = new MySqlCommand(q2, conn);
                conn.Open();
                if ((long)(cmd2.ExecuteScalar() ?? 0) == 0)//user is not exist
                {
                    conn.Close();
                    string q1 = "insert into RecoverPwdStatus values('" + getUser() + "','" + code.ToString() + "');";
                    MySqlCommand cmd1 = new MySqlCommand(q1, conn);
                    conn.Open();
                    MySqlDataReader rdr1 = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
                    conn.Close();
                }
                else 
                {
                    conn.Close();
                    string q3 = "update recoverpwdstatus set guidcode='"+code.ToString()+"' where uid='"+getUser()+"';";
                    MySqlCommand cmd3 = new MySqlCommand(q3, conn);
                    conn.Open();
                    MySqlDataReader rdr3 = cmd3.ExecuteReader();
                    conn.Close();
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex )
            {
                LabelMessage.Text = ex.Message;
            }
        }
```

// Method to display confirmation message as given bellow, I need to show this message using label or message box. I need solution over here only.

```
 private static void SendCompletedCallback(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            var result = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();
            if (e.Cancelled)
                result.SetResult("Sending Mail is Canceled...!!");
            if (e.Error != null)
                result.SetResult(string.Format("{0} {1}", e.UserState, e.Error));
            else
                result.SetResult("Email sent successfully.");
        }
```

Comment: are you facing any error ?

Comment: Not at all but the solution I used is do nothing. If I am trying to use some code like javascript to  display message its showing error. That is red underline for the  such code. (not acceptable)

Answer (score 0):

This call

```
  client.SendCompleted += new SendCompletedEventHandler(SendCompletedCallback);  
  client.SendAsync(msg, userstate);
```

is asynchronous, that is mean that after the page have been send to the user is probably called and you lose the information's. It works for an application but not for web page and web application that way.

Comment: Then what is alternative solution for this? In case of web app.

Comment: @DipakAkhade Find a synchronous example to use. (google it) or just wait there to send it.

Comment: I am not getting optimum solution on google. I am waiting for some code.